# Mobile Responsive has a scrolling problem

Tags: android, wordpress, mobile, responsive, smooth-scrolling

So http://www.made4u.my this is the website I’ve done currently. It is built from WordPress. It works well in iOS and desktop. But when it’s in Android （all kind or brand of Android devices) with ANY kind of browsers, it having scrolling problem as the mobile site will keep “jumping” to bottom.

Experience with the Android devices. Scroll slowly to the bottom, then back to top. Slowly….. or normal speed. It will keep “jumping” here and there.

I recorded a video of the scrolling bottom and uploaded on youtube and below is the link.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lbz_C44kFjc